# Get id + variable from html in jquery

Tags: html, jquery, variables, click

How is it possible to find a specific id + variable from an html p element in a different function to avoid $(this).parent().... without onclick(object.id) or just searching for id = comment-object (not unique)?

I want to click a button to edit the specific p-tag element by getting the unique id.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 function renderCommentLine(object) {

        var htmlStart =
            "<div class='media cfe-media'>" + authorImage +
            "<div class='media-body'>" +
            author + "<small> vor " +
            timesince +
            "</small>" +
            "<p id='comment-object-" + object.id + "' class='media-content' + data-id='" + object.id + "'>" +
            object.content + "</p>" + "<small>" + '</div>'

       
        if (object.user) {
            if (object.user.username == authUsername) {
                htmlStart = htmlStart +
                    '<div class="dropdown">' +
                    '<button id="dropdown-button" data-toggle="dropdown">' +
                    '<span style="font-size: 3rem;" class="material-icons">more_vert</span>' +
                    '</button>' +

                    '<div class="dropdown-menu">' +
                    '<button class="media-edit" id="dropdown-item" type="button">' +
                    '<span style="font-size: 2.5rem;" class="material-icons">create</span>' +
                    'Bearbeiten</button></li>' +

                    '<button class="comment-delete" id="dropdown-item" type="button">' +
                    '<span style="font-size: 2.5rem;" class="material-icons">delete</span>' +
                    'Löschen</button></li>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>'
            }
        }
        var html_ = htmlStart + "</small></div></div>"
        return html_
    }
}}
    

    $(document).on('click', '.media-edit', function(e){ 
          e.preventDefault()
          var contentHolder = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().find(".media-content")
        **//  var contentHolder = ("#comment-object" + object.id)**
          var contentTxt = contentHolder.text() 
          var objectId = contentHolder.attr('data-id') 
          contentHolder.replaceWith(generateEditForm(contentTxt, objectId))
        })
```

Comment: Without seeing the html that connects `.media-edit` and `.media-content` then its hard to tell you where the problem is. But I would assume that it might have something to do with all the `.parent()`

Comment: Again, the structure of your HTML is key to responding to your question meaningfully. So, does every `p[id^="comment-object-"]` have it's own button? What's the placing of the buttons relative to the `p` tags?

Comment: There is a button rendered for every comment-object but with a non unique id. So the click routine should handle the edit of the comment for the id comment-object- + object.id. Maybe theres a chance to give the object to the click-event?

Comment: The Solution was sending object.id with the button, to use the variable to find the id of the content tag via $("#comment-object-"+ id +"")